# Update Error in cell

Tags: c#, datagridview, tableadapter

When I edit my `DataGridView`'s cell I want to immediately update my MSSQL database. I added a `CellEndEdit' event handler. Also I added autogenerated bindingsource and`TableAdapter`.

It works correctly but whenever I want to edit my value I get an error. Actually, I wrote an update method with `SqlDataAdapter`. But in this time I use auto-generated `TableAdapter`. I don't know what to do. I try this one but I got an error.

**Note**: `DataSet11`, `loginTableAdapter`, and `Bindingsource1` are auto generated and work.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
   SqlCommandBuilder querybuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(loginTableAdapter);
   querybuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
   loginTableAdapter.Update(dataset11);
}
```

Comment: it doesnot report error. look everything find. but i doesnt save changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
        private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            {
                SqlCommandBuilder querybuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(loginTableAdapter);
                querybuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
                loginTableAdapter.Update(dataset11);
            }
        }

        //or if you has a bindingSource
        private void bindingSource1_CurrentItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            {
                SqlCommandBuilder querybuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(loginTableAdapter);
                querybuilder.GetUpdateCommand();
                loginTableAdapter.Update(dataset11);
            }
        }
```